# How to capture x screen using PHP, shell_exe and scrot

Tags: php, linux, bash, screenshot

I'm building a web page screen capture application for an internal R&D project.

Environment: Ubuntu 9.04 (default desktop install), Apache, PHP.

So far I've got a bash script that takes one parameter (URL), fires up firefox, grabs the screen and saves it as a PNG. I've tried running this from terminal and it works fine.

Here's the Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox $1 # Start firefox and go to the passed in URL
scrot -d 5 test.png # Take screen grab with 5 second delay
```

Next I created a simple PHP page that uses shell_exec to run the script:

```
<?
  // Sample URL
  $url = 'http://www.google.com'; 
  // Run the script
  shell_exec('sh script.sh ' . $url);
  // Out put HTML to display image
  echo '<img src="test.png" />';
?>
```

However, when the PHP page is called the screen is not captured.
A quick look in the apache error logs show the following message:

> ```
> Error: no display specified
> giblib error: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah
> ```

I'm guessing this is because apache is running as a different user and hasn't got access to my X display.

So, can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong or how I can capture the current user display.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launching firefox from PHP running under Apache seems to me like a bad idea (it definitly feels wrong).

The way I would do that :

- a PHP webpage (which runs under Apache) that receives the URL ; something like a form, for instance

  - that page inserts the URL in a database-like system, that will be used as a queue
  - this URL is marked as "to process"
- a PHP (or another language) script, totally independant from Apache ; for instance, launched by the crontab

  - this scripts selects an URL from the queue in the database (least recent one, for instance), and marks it as "processing"
  - it then lauches your shell-script, which launches firefox and does the screenshot
  - one the screenshot is done, the URL in the queue is marked as "done", and the screenshot's path is associated to the URL
  - this will work, as it is independant from Apache
- another web page displays the queue, and the status of each URL ("to process", "processing", "done + path to the screenshot"

  - you can even imagine having an association betwen a user and an URL, to not display every URL+screenshot to everyone.

With this system, several advantages :

- php+apache for the webpages
- php outside of apache for the "system" parts
- you can have the webpages on one server
- and you can have several machines (linux, windows, mac -- maybe using virtual machines) to make the screenshots

  - allow you to get screenshots from different OSes
  - scales way better ^^

It's not really an answer to the question, but I think it's a better way... Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive response.
My original method was a very quick idea mock-up, but you're right, it does feel *wrong* and your proposed system is a better approach.

Comment: You're welcome :-) (only problem is that I am now thinking "this would be fun to code, let's do it" -- except I already have tooooo much to do :-D )

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [guide](http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/xvfb-firefox.html) to do screen-capturing using firefox and [xvfb](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/Xvfb.1.html). The advantage with this approach is that there will be no firefox windows opening and closing on your main X server. It will also solve your problem with permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you run your bash and firefox as the same user as apache?

Comment: Can you elaborate further please.

I'm assuming that Apache runs the bash script as it's own user which doesn't have X running? I'm a bit of a noob to this so in the process of learning how it all works.